# +~JF tmp files process flow / life cycle in jasper java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, temporary-files

I see many questions on +~JF tmp files being created when the jasper report runs and but I am having really hard time find more information about these tmp files life cycle.

- Are +~JF tmp files always created for the first time any jasper report runs?  so far, that has been our case.
- Is there a case when +JF tmp files won't be created during the jasper report run?  It has NOT been the case for us.
- What causes these files to be created. (similar to 2nd question but what exact process in jasper library / engine responsible for these tmp files, etc.)
- When do they go away? The tmp files disappear if the server shuts down gracefully but will it ever go away before the server shuts down?  that has not been the case for us. So far, only disappear when the server shuts down gracefully.

I have no problem having these tmp files being created.  It's perfectly fine but I want to understand the life cycle of these files better.

Any help is greatly appreciated